# Specifying in and out along with controls in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Considering the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \node at (1,0) [rectangle,draw,minimum height=.6cm] (a1) {A};
        \node at (4.2,-3.5) [rectangle,draw,minimum height=.6cm] (e3) {B};

        \draw[->,thick,out=200] (e3) .. controls ($(a1)+(-2,-2)$) .. (a1);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

How can one specify the in and out angles for the starting and the final nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keys `in`,`out` are for `to` paths for example you can write

```
\draw[->,thick] (e3) to[in=200,out=200] (a1);
```

However if you still want to use angle arguments and Bezier curves then you can add a polar coordinate

```
\draw[->,thick] (e3) .. controls ++(200:1) and ++(200:2) .. (a1);
```

Here the first control point is taken as relative to the start point and the second is relative to the final point.

The Bezier curve with single control point is taken to both start and the final points.

Comment: Some additional remarks to the first solution that might help you achieve the curve you are looking for: The length of the curve can be controlled with the `loosness`-parameter (use `to[in=<in-angle>, out=<out-angle>, loosness=<value>]`) and to really see the desired angle between the curve and the border of the node (and not the center) use e.g. `(e3.west)` instead of `(e3)`.